# How to add listener event to JList elements which are added by DefaultListModel object?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have created 2 JLists 'addGroupList' and 'addApkList'. I am adding elements to addGroupList using model.addElement(arrayList1.get(arrayList1.size()-1)); the thing is, I want to update addApkList based on selected value of addGroupList. For this, I'm trying to add event listener so that I can act upon something when list item is selected but the event is not trigerring.
What do I do to accomplish this?
following is the code I'm using.

```
    model1 = new DefaultListModel();
    model2 = new DefaultListModel();

    addApkList = new JList(model1);
    addGroupList = new JList(model2);

    scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane1.setViewportView(addApkList);
    scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane2.setViewportView(addGroupList);
```

this way i've defined JList.
in following way i've added elements to addGroupList

```
model1.addElement(arrayList1.get(arrayList1.size()-1));
```

and in following way I've added listener to it.

```
addGroupList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
            if (!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
              System.out.println("Selection trigerred");
            }
        }
    });
```

There doesnt seem to happen any change with this code. what m i doing wrong?
I've also tried following

```
model1.addListDataListener(new ListDataListener() {

            @Override
            public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent lde) {
                System.out.println("ddddddddddd");
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent lde) {
                System.out.println("ddddddddddd");
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent lde) {
                System.out.println("ddddddddddd");
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you sure you dont need an implementation ListDataListener for your ListModel?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataListener.html

Comment: please why, reason for ....

Comment: I tried ListDataListener. its not working. updating the code I used while trying ListDataListener in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In following way i've added elements to addGroupList
>
> ```
> model1.addElement(arrayList1.get(arrayList1.size()-1));
> ```

No you haven't. `model1` is the list model for `addApkList` not `addGroupList`:

```
 addApkList = new JList(model1);
```

It should be `model2.addElement(arrayList1.get(arrayList1.size()-1))`.

In any case I suspect you're expecting for a [ListSelectionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html) being fired when you just simply add an item to list model. That won't happen. You need to set the added item as the selected one:

```
Object item = arrayList1.get(arrayList1.size()-1);
model2.addElement(item);
addGroupList.setSelectedValue(item, true);
```

Take a look to [JList.setSelectedValue(Object anObject, boolean shouldScroll)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectedValue%28java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) for further details.

Comment: isn't easier to share one ListSelectionModel for both Jlists

Comment: okay that helped. Thank you :)
I assigned model1 to addGroupList and model2 to addApkList. It
worked but now when I'm clicking on list item, "Selection trigerred" is displayed 2 times if list contains 2 items and 3 times if list contains 3 items. What is the reason?

Comment: @user2713104 Maybe you're adding a new `ListSelectionListener` to `addGroupList` every time you add a new item. That would explain this behaviour. You just need to add the listener once, when you initialize the list.

Answer (score 2):

> I have created 2 JLists 'addGroupList' and 'addApkList'. I am adding
>   elements to addGroupList using
>   model.addElement(arrayList1.get(arrayList1.size()-1)); the thing is, I
>   want to update addApkList based on selected value of addGroupList. For
>   this, I'm trying to add event listener so that I can act upon
>   something when list item is selected but the event is not trigerring.
>   What do I do to accomplish this? following is the code I'm using.

for example

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Testing extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultListModel listModelEmpty = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList list = new JList(listModel);
    private JList listEmpty = new JList(listModelEmpty);
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    private int currentSelectedRow = 0;
    private int xX = 0;

    public Testing() {
        setLocation(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            listModel.addElement("" + x);
            xX++;
        }
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
                if (!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    System.out.println("Selection trigerred");
                }
            }
        });
        JScrollPane spEmpty = new JScrollPane(listEmpty);
        panel.add(spEmpty);
        panel.add(sp);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Reset Model CastingModel");
        add(btn1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //list.clearSelection();
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
                model.removeAllElements();
                for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                    model.addElement("" + (x + xX));
                    xX++;
                }
                list.setModel(model);
            }
        });

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Reset Model directly from Model");
        add(btn2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //list.clearSelection();
                listModel.removeAllElements();
                for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                    listModel.addElement("" + (x + xX));
                    xX++;
                }
            }
        });
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Testing().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please take a look at here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l79ho0v25c3vswr/Screenshot%20%2895%29.png

as shown, when I create a group, it gets listed in left list. now when i press on say 'Nikhil' nothing happens. I am trying to change hatchet (on right side list) to something else.